# How to store multiple vectors in elements of a list?

Tags: r, list

I have generated a file that looks like this (here is an extract, roughly each one of two files with names having columns 1 and 2 in common are multiplied by a different parameter and the best fit, i.e. the lowest chi2, is returned in column 3 with the appropriate parameters in columns 4 and 5):

```
10 05 0.42 0.13 0.01   
10 10 0.30 0.12 0.01  
10 15 0.25 0.11 0.07  
15 05 0.29 0.12 0.01  
15 10 0.25 0.11 0.06  
15 15 0.23 0.10 0.02  
20 05 0.25 0.11 0.03  
20 10 0.23 0.12 0.04  
20 15 0.23 0.13 0.05  
25 05 0.23 0.10 0.03  
25 10 0.23 0.10 0.08  
25 15 0.24 0.09 0.05
```

I am starting/learning to use lists as my codes are really to slow using `for` loops (currently I am using 4 `for` loops so it's insanely long), and I don't know enough to re-write my optimisation code so it does not take 8 hours to work. So instead, to reorganise the output I was wondering if it would be possible to create a list, say `mytemplist`, that reads:

```
> mytemplist  
$5 
[1] 10 15 20 25  
[2] 0.42 0.29 0.25 0.23  
[3] 0.13 0.12 0.11 0.10
[4] 0.01 0.01 0.03 0.03  

$10  
[1] 10 15 20 25  
[2] 0.30 0.25 0.23 0.23
[3] 0.12 0.11 0.12 0.10  
[4] 0.01 0.06 0.04 0.08  

$15  
[1] 10 15 20 25  
[2] 0.25 0.23 0.23 0.24  
[3] 0.11 0.10 0.13 0.09  
[4] 0.07 0.02 0.05 0.05
```

I have looked at questions about lists and I could only sort that out by creating lists within lists which is not helping here.

---

EDIT:
the accepted answer replies to the specific question above, to answer @rawr post I join how the file is generated (it's not pretty, I am not using opt so far as I will evolve the code to optimise with bigger freedom around the data points):
note: typical file to read are 2-column file (just lists of numbers) and named a10b05s and a10b05t
dataname is also a 2-column file
in those 3 files the first column is the same and represents the pivots
need to find par[1] and par[2] such that par[1]*a10b05s + par[2]*a10b05t best fit data

```
par <- rep(NA, 2)
pivot <- read.table(dataname)[[1]]
data2fit <- read.table(dataname)[[2]]

for (i in 1:10){
    vala <- 10+5*(i-1)
    namei <- paste("a", vala, sep="")

    for (j in 1:10){
        #creates a coordinates for storage
        cglobal <- (i-1) * 10 + j           

        valb <- 5+5*(j-1)
        namej1 <- paste(namei, "b", valb, "s", sep="")
        namej2 <- paste(namei, "b", valb, "t", sep="")
        infile1 <- read.table(namej1)
        infile2 <- read.table(namej2)

        # infile1 prominent wrt infile2 so first quick determination of par1 
        tempspace1 <- seq(0.001, 0.009, 0.001)
        par1_s1 <- c(tempspace1, tempspace1*10, tempspace1*100) 
        opt1_par1 <- rep(NA, length(par1))

        # set a pivot for comparison at position named temppivot find par1 wrt temppivot
        for(k in 1:length(par1){
            opt1_par1[k] <- abs(par1_s1[k]*infile1[[1]][temppivot] - data2fit[temppivot])
        }

        par[1] <- par1_s1[match(min(opt1_par1)), opt1_par1]

        # set a space for a finer fit for par[1]
        par1_s2 <- seq(par[1]-5*par[1]/10, par[1]+5*par[1]/10, par[1]/100)

        # set a space to fit par[2] note that there is an option in the code to choose btw 0.001-0.01, 0.01-0.1 etc.
        tempspace2 <- seq(0.001, 0.009, 0.0001)
        par2 <- c(tempspace2, tempspace2*10, tempspace2*100)
        chi2 <- rep(NA, length(par1_s2)*length(par2))
        #data2fit 

        for(z in 1:length(par1_s2)){
            for(w in 1:length(par2)){
                par[1] <- par1_s2[z]
                par[2] <- par2[w]
                thesum <- rep(NA, length(pivot))
                    for(h in 1:length(pivot)){
                        c1 <- pivot[h]
                        thesum[h] <- par[1] * infile[[1]][c1] + par[2] * infile2[[1]][c1]
                    }
            c2 <- (z-1) * length(par2) + w
            chi2[c2] <- sum((thesum-data2fit)^2/thesum)
            }
        }

        whichbestfit <- match(min(chi2), chi2)
        chi2min <- min(chi2)

        localparfinder <- function(x){
            temp1 <- trunc(x/length(par2)) + 1
            temp2 <- x - (temp1 -1) * length(par2)
            y <- c(par1_s2[temp1], par2[temp2])
            }

        par <- localparfinder(whichbestfit)

        # creates the table of the original post
        storage[cglobal,] <- c(vala, valb, chi2min, par[1], par[2])
    }
}


write.table(storage, file=paste("storage_", format(Sys.time(), "%d%b_%H%M"), ".dat", sep="")
```

Comment: it would be better to show us how you generated these results rather than taking what you already have and manipulating that into what you want (I mean, this seems like an unnecessary intermediary step that could be avoided by the previous step)

Comment: I edited the post to show how I generate the file, obviously there is many things I would change (especially I don't need that many `for` loops) but since I had the table I was looking for I did not want to redo everything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `by` and `t`ranspose, like this:

```
by(mydf[-2], mydf[[2]], t)
# mydf[[2]]: 5
#        1     4     7    10
# V1 10.00 15.00 20.00 25.00
# V3  0.42  0.29  0.25  0.23
# V4  0.13  0.12  0.11  0.10
# V5  0.01  0.01  0.03  0.03
# ----------------------------------------------------------- 
# mydf[[2]]: 10
#        2     5     8    11
# V1 10.00 15.00 20.00 25.00
# V3  0.30  0.25  0.23  0.23
# V4  0.12  0.11  0.12  0.10
# V5  0.01  0.06  0.04  0.08
# ----------------------------------------------------------- 
# mydf[[2]]: 15
#        3     6     9    12
# V1 10.00 15.00 20.00 25.00
# V3  0.25  0.23  0.23  0.24
# V4  0.11  0.10  0.13  0.09
# V5  0.07  0.02  0.05  0.05
```

---

The result of the above is a `list` with a class of `by`. If you used `unclass` on it, it would be similar to the `split` + `lapply` approach.

Comment: thanks! very neat solution as well, and indeed:
`unclass(by(mydf[-2], mydf[[2]], t))`
does the same as
`lapply(split(df[-2], df$V2), t)`
and I like that you keep more info before applying `unclass`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possibility:

```
lst <- split(df[-2], df$V2)   # split according to colum 2 and drop column 2 in the output

lst <- lapply(lst, t)         # transpose each list element
lst
#   $`5`
#       1     4     7    10
#V1 10.00 15.00 20.00 25.00
#V3  0.42  0.29  0.25  0.23
#V4  0.13  0.12  0.11  0.10
#V5  0.01  0.01  0.03  0.03
#
#$`10`
#       2     5     8    11
#V1 10.00 15.00 20.00 25.00
#V3  0.30  0.25  0.23  0.23
#V4  0.12  0.11  0.12  0.10
#V5  0.01  0.06  0.04  0.08
#
#$`15`
#       3     6     9    12
#V1 10.00 15.00 20.00 25.00
#V3  0.25  0.23  0.23  0.24
#V4  0.11  0.10  0.13  0.09
#V5  0.07  0.02  0.05  0.05
```

If you like it more compact, you could also nest the split and lapply like this:

```
lst <- lapply(split(df[-2], df$V2), t)
```

Comment: If the answer is `split` + `lapply`, a more direct solution is *usually* found with `by` :-)